# If $f(x)+g(x)+h(x)=f(y)+g(y)+h(y)$ then for every $n$, $f(n)+g(n)+h(n)$=constant

Tags: functions, proof-writing

We deal quite often with situations in which we have something like $a_1b_1=a_2b_2$ and then we say that the product $ab$ is constant.

A similar situation arose when I was seeing  the derivation of Bernoulli's principal (physics) in which the second last step looks like $$\frac{P_1}{\rho}+gh_1+\frac{v_1^2}{2}=\frac{P_2}{\rho}+gh_2+\frac{v_2^2}{2}$$

Here $h$ denotes the height, $P$ denotes pressure and $v$ denotes the velocity. $\rho, g$ are constant terms density and acceleration due to gravity.

Then next step is $\frac{P}{\rho}+gh+\frac{v^2}{2}=$ Constant.

Now a question popped up in my mind.

The terms $\frac{P}{\rho}$, $gh$ and $\frac{v^2}{2}$ are dependent to the variables $P,h,v$ and thus each term can be considered as a function.

So the second last step in Derivation is similar to:

$$f(x)+g(x)+h(x)=f(y)+g(y)+h(y)$$ And last step is $f(n)+g(n)+h(n)=$constant.

That's what I want to prove, that $f(x)+g(x)+h(x)=f(y)+g(y)+h(y)$ then for every $n$ $f(n)+g(n)+h(n)=$constant. Further, If this thing is not true then why we use the similar argument in derivation of principal??

I am a beginner at function so please forget me if I am asking something very-very easy. Provide as much as information as you can. Thanks.

Comment: In general a function F(x) that satisfies F(x)=F(y) for two arbitrary x,y does not need to be constant (think about a parabola for instance). If it holds *for all* x,y then it indeed is constant, as it is in this case.

Comment: Do you mean $f(x)+g(x)+h(x)=f(y)+g(y)+h(y)$ for all $x,y$ or just for a couple of values?

Comment: I mean $F(x)=f(x)+g(x)+h(x)$ implicitly.

Comment: The parameters in Bernoulli's principle are not considered functions of $P,h,v$ but rather as functions of position $x$ along a streamline. The first equation is really saying that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ for all $x_1,x_2$ along the steamline. Fixing $x_1$ and varying $x_2$ allows you to conclude $f(x)$ is constant along the streamline for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define

$F(x)=f(x)+g(x)+h(x)$.

Then your problem can be restated as if

$F(x)=F(y)$ **for all** $x,y$ in the domain of the function (this part is misleading in the question but very relevant), then $F(x)$ is constant.

To show it we are going to apply that if $F'(x)=0$ then $F(x)$ is constant. From the definition of derivative we have

$F'(x)=lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}=0$

where the last step is due to the fact that $F(x)=F(y)$ for all $x,y$.

Comment: $F(x) = F(y)$ for all pairs in the domain sounds like the definition of constant to me, not sure there is anything to prove.